# Use adjective “insured” as adverb in “My father worked as insured in this company”

Tags: adverbs

Can I say the following?

> My father worked as insured in this company for ten years.

It seems weird to me . What I mean is that my father got a job with social security benefits. I asked if I can used “as insured “ instead of “with social security benefits”.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "insured"? As a nominal it ordinarily means a person covered by an insurance policy.

Comment: I mean my father worked with social security . Does sentence above give this meaning ?

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean, I'm afraid, @Foreignstudent

Comment: My father got a job with social security benefits.i asked if i can used “as insured “ instead of “with social security benefits”.

Comment: I'd say “My father's job in this company had fringe benefits including insurance.”

Comment: In the US, you might be able to say something like "... worked as (a) *statutory employee* ..." to mean that the person had social security earnings and was having the necessary participant and employer contributions withheld.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, @Foreign student, your explanation "a job with social security benefits" is not a recognisable phrase in English, either British or (judging from StoneyB's answer) American. I can think of a couple of things it might mean, but it's not clear to me.

It looks as if your social welfare and employment system is so different that the terms just don't translate. Given that, it is *possible* that "worked as insured" might be meaningful to somebody who understood your benefits model; but to us in the US and the UK, it doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be meaningful in the US, where "Social Security" is not strictly speaking "insurance" but a government program nominally funded by payroll taxes on both employees and employers (self-employed payors are taxed at a higher level). It is not the job but payment of the tax which entitles payors to retirement and disability income benefits. And those benefits do not end when the employee leaves the job, so the employee cannot be said to be employed "with benefits" or "as an insured".